# Не работает Android Designer под Visual Studio

Tags: android, android-sdk, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Доброго всем дня! 
Решил попробовать себя в Xamarin. Создал проект на Single View в Visual Studio 2015. И выдается такое предупреждение:

> An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer.
>   Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path
>   on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs
>   for more details

Я так понял, что в студии должен быть визуальный редактор (дизайнер) компонентов под Xamarin.Forms? Или просто визуальный редактор? Проверил настройки (см картинку). Вроде все на своем месте

Поиск по гуглу привел меня еще к [одной иде](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224865/). Может ее лучше использовать, чем Visual Studio? Кто чем пользуется?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms не имеет визуального редактора, только нативные проекты. (ну и/или предопределенные рендеры в проектах).

Как вариант(для Forms), можете установить на телефон Xamarin live player и видеть отображение изменений UI сразу на телефоне, редактируя Xaml код.

https://www.xamarin.com/live

Про ошибку - проверьте, что установили все нужные SDK для платформы как в примере:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/using-the-sdk-manager/